# How to get 1-20 Using Regex

Tags: regex

Hello boys my regex code don't work!

```
if(preg_match("#\d{1,2}(?!\d)|20#", "207")){
    echo 'yes';
}else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following adaptation of your code:

```
if (preg_match("#\b([01]?\d|20)\b#", "207")) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Notice the above code will `yes` for `"20 207"`.

If you only a match when the whole word is the number, use `^` and `$` to delimiter the string:

```
if (preg_match("#^\b([01]?\d|20)\b$#", "20 207")) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior. Working perfect

Answer (score 0):

To validate number range from 1-20 you can use:

```
'/\b([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\b/'
```

Comment: Thanks. But if the second parameter is 0, echo 'no';

Comment: What is 2nd parameter here?